# Questions and concerns

Tags: riemann-hypothesis

I would like to know if solving the riemann hypothesis as well as the twin prime conjecture are still questions within mathematics? I have been unable to find credible resources.

Comment: They are still open problems.

Comment: Some important works on prime gap problems have been published five years ago (notably one by Yitang Zhang and one by James Maynard), but twin primes is still open. Riemann hypothesis is open. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics) and [Open Problem Garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/) have rather comprehensive lists.